# How to execute a function inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, input

Is there something wrong in this piece of python code?

My issue is that when the run_again() executes and asks for an input whenever I type "n" everything goes fine but the run() function doesn't executes when I type "y". *Why is it so?*

I have tried doing the process of run_again() without creating a function but it showed the same bug.

```
import random

print("Welcome to the Snake water gun game!")
chance = 1
counter = 10
player_p = 0
comp_p = 0
choices = ["Snake", "Water", "Gun"]

def run():
global choices
global chance
global player_p
global comp_p
global counter
while chance > 0 and chance <= 10:
    a = random.choice(choices)
    counter -= 1
    print("Choose one from below:\n1.Snake(s)\n2.Water(w)\n3.Gun(g)")
    decision = input("Type here:")
    if decision == "s" and a == "Snake":
        chance += 1
        print(f"Draw. {counter} times left.")
    elif decision == 's' and a == "Water":
        chance += 1
        print(f"You Won! {counter} times left.\n-------------------------------")
        player_p += 1
    elif decision == "s" and a == "Gun":
        chance += 1
        print(f"You lost. {counter} times left.\n-------------------------------")
        comp_p += 1
    elif decision == "w" and a == 'Snake':
        chance += 1
        print(f"You lost. {counter} times left.\n-------------------------------")
        comp_p += 1
    elif decision == "w" and a == "Water":
        chance += 1
        print(f"Draw. {counter} times left.\n-------------------------------")
    elif decision == "w" and a == "Gun":
        chance += 1
        print(f"You Won! {counter} times left.\n-------------------------------")
        player_p += 1
    elif decision == "g" and a == "Snake":
        chance += 1
        print(f"You Won! {counter} times left.\n-------------------------------")
        player_p += 1
    elif decision == "g" and a == "Water":
        chance += 1
        print(f"You lost. {counter} times left.\n-------------------------------")
        comp_p += 1
    elif decision == "g" and a == "Gun":
        chance += 1
        print(f"Draw. {counter} times left.\n-------------------------------")
    
run()

print("Your score:", player_p)
print("Computer's score:", comp_p)

def winner():
    if player_p > comp_p:
        print("------------------------\nYou Won! Congratulations")
    elif player_p < comp_p:
        print("------------------------\nComputer Won! Better luck next time.")
    else:
        print("---------------\nIt's a DRAW!")

winner()

def run_again():
    q = input("Do you want to play again(y/n):")
    if q == 'n':
        print("Oh, okay")
    elif q == 'y':
        run()
run_again()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works

```
def run_again():
    q = input("Do you want to play again(y/n):")
    if q == 'n':
        print("Oh, okay")
    elif q == 'y':
        run()

def run():
  print("Hi")
run_again()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no run() function created in the given code by you, so how can it be called. You have to create a function named run() as per the given code. See  the below code for better understanding:-

```
def run():
    print("Let's play again")
def run_again():
    q = input("Do you want to play again(y/n):")
    if q == 'n':
        print("Oh, okay")
    elif q == 'y':
        run()
run_again()
```

You can edit the run() function in the updated code as per your choice.